# Make submenu vertical layout in an existing nav menu

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-transitions

I have a menu nav function in css3 and html

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" >Sec1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Sec2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Sec3</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sec4</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

but How can the submenu be like:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

**--Fiddle-**
[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhJXt/30/)

Comment: it isn't very clear what you are trying to accomplish, can you explain what you want exactly because you have multiple items scattered in that fiddle...

Comment: Yes, I want a menu that contains 4 sections, and in section 3, I want a vertical submenu. How to accomplish that?

Comment: I posted a jsfiddle and a detailed explanation as to what I did, you should take a look and let me know if you want any other things to happen, I'll try my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand what you are looking for and have made my jsfiddle as close as possible to yours. Instead of using the images you provided, I used icon fonts, which are useful if you plan on using many images. I got my icon font from Keyamoon at [icomoon.io](http://icomoon.io/). It's a really good tool to have and you should definitely use it for any other icons you need. I picked mine from Icon Minia by Egemen Kapusuz. You can see the icons I used and if those are the only ones you need just download the files from the @font-face urls in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/mhJXt/242/), or from here:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IHK';
    src:url('http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/icon font testing/IHK.eot');
    src:url('http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/icon font testing/IHK.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/icon font testing/IHK.svg#IHK') format('svg'),
        url('http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/icon font testing/IHK.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/icon font testing/IHK.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

You can just copy the links from here and it will give you the font file to download if you only need these 3 icons. Icon fonts are great because instead of loading 1 image for each background or icon or whatever, you can package the icon fonts all together into 1 HTTP request, making them more efficient in the transfer, and also more customizable. Icon fonts are just a font, so you can also manipulate them much more easily; you can change the color of the font, the anti-aliasing, just like a real text font.

I rewrote your code with some jQuery because yours seemed very jumbled and a little hard to understand, so if you would like to use my exact jsfiddle, you will need to add a jquery source link either from a CDN or host your own copy on your server. [jquery.com](http://jquery.com) will have tons of info about that.

So for my HTML:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Sec2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="current">Sec3</a></li>
        <li><a href="contacto.html" >Sec4</a></li>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="documents" data-icon="&#xe000">Documents</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="messages" data-icon="&#xe001">Messages</a></li>
            <br>
            <li><a href="#" class="signout" data-icon="&#xe002">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The html has some new attributes, which I titled data-icon. I used these to incorporate the icons from the icon font without adding an official element in the DOM. Browser support for this is a little new, so you should look into a redundant icon scheme just in case users are using an old browser that doesn't support icon fonts and the other new features that you also had like `border-radius` and `transitions`.

The CSS was modified a lot to use psuedo selectors, which are very useful. Additionally, I now have the nav bar working from jQuery, so it should be supported well because jQuery is a cross-browser JavaScript libary.

The only thing I couldn't fix was this little problem where the hovered text in the 2nd navigation level would jump, I don't know why that happens, I will look into it, but for now, [this is what](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/mhJXt/242/) I was able to produce for you.

Comment: superb! I want to reproduce your fiddle, I am using already  jquery adding it as: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>`

would that be enough?, I am doing some testing

Comment: I'd suggest grabbing the latest version of jquery, which is 1.9.0 as of 1/19/2013

Comment: Oh and I've found the problem with the little glitch, I'll give you a new url here: http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/mhJXt/242/ and update the one in my answer.

Comment: I am not getting the submenu as in your fiddle even adding the css and jquery you wrote, do you think I am missing something? 
I am Adding 

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` I am suspencting this has to do with the Fonts...

Comment: do you have a website/server you are testing from, or is this local?

Comment: Oh, so that is why, Testing local, let me try it in a server, I also  added <script src=" http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23031/discussion-between-ilan-biala-and-cminor)

Answer (score 1):

I Change a little your CSS And Html File

Css:

```
nav
{
position: absolute;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
width: 620px;
top: 43px;
right: -12px;
background: transparent;
}
nav ul li
{
float: left;
line-height: normal;
}
nav ul li a
{
font-size: 28px;
font-family: 'Yanone Kaffeesatz', arial, sans-serif;
color: black;
text-transform: capitalize;
font-weight: normal;
display: block;  /* IE6, IE7 line height fix */
padding: 15px;
background-color: transparent;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 6px;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul
{
display: inline;
}
nav ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #43AEF2;
padding: 15px;
color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
nav ul li a.current
{
background-color: #43aef2;
color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li
{
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
margin-right: 10px;
color: #666;
transition: 0.3s;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s;
-moz-transition: 0.3s;
-o-transition: 0.3s;
-ms-transition: 0.3s;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li:last-child
{
margin-right: 0;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li:hover
{
color: #000;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li:hover:after
{
color: #bbb;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li:after
{
margin-left: 10px;
content: '';
color: #bbb;
}
nav ul:not(.first) li:last-child:after
{
content: '';
}
.content_menu
{
float: left;
width: 274px;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.content_menu ul
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: none;
}
.content_menu ul li
{
float: none;
padding-bottom: 16px;
}
.content_menu ul li a
{
font-size: 14px;
line-height: normal;
color: #33CC99;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.content_menu ul li a:hover
{
color: #33CC99;
}
/*  submenu  */
.menu
{
display: none;
position: absolute;
background: black;
width: 140px;
}
.menu li a
{
display: block;
padding: 0 14px 0 30px;
margin: 6px 0;
line-height: 28px;
text-decoration: none;
border-left: 1px solid #393942;
border-right: 1px solid #4f5058;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;
color: #f3f3f3;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
-webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li:first-child a
{
border-left: none;
}
.menu li:last-child a
{
border-right: none;
}
.menu li:hover > a
{
color: #33CC99;
}
.menu ul
{
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
background: #1f2024;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > ul
{
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu ul li
{
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;
-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}
.menu li:hover > a
{
height: auto;
}
.menu li a
{
width: 100px;
padding: 4px 0 4px 40px;
margin: 0;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #353539;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a
{
border: none;
}
/* Icons */
.menu a.documents
{
background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/docs.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}
.menu a.messages
{
background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/bubble.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}
.menu a.signout
{
background: url(http://designmodo.com/demo/css3dropdownmenu/img/arrow.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}
.menu li
{
float: none;
display: initial;
}
```

HTML

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" >Sec1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Sec2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="current">Sec3</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="documents">Documents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="messages">Messages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="contacto.html" >Sec4</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the result as in the image?

Comment: Yes It Can Be. I Edit The Post.